# How do I monitor a daemon on Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, daemon

I have an upstart script which runs a node.js deamon continuously.

What I'm trying to do is to restart this daemon when/if it fails.

I have little or no idea how to go about this.

Any insight greatly appreciated,

Comment: I've just discovered forever (`sudo npm install forever`)

Answer (score 1):

Add the following line to the end of your upstart script:

```
respawn
```

That's exactly for the case you described: Upstart then watches it and starts it as soon it is "exiting" -- with just one exception: If it is intentionally stopped by `service xyz stop` it will be stopped and not respawn until it is intentionally started again.